# JQuery Deferred how to use resolve and promise to determine function end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  in an html page that I'd like to show a spinner on while a JQuery function is running. Since its asynchronous I am trying to use deferred to determine when the function completed

the code in the html page

```
 var req = jslongfunc(value);
 req.done(function( response){
           spinner.stop();
 });
```

The code in the JS page that contains jslongfunc

```
function jslongfunc() {
   rdef = $.Deferred();
   $.getJSON('mycode, function(data){
   ... do lots of stuff here ...
  });
  setTimeout(function () {
             r.resolve();
        }, 4500);
   return r.promise();
```

The spinner seems to run for 4500 regardless of when the jslongfunc finished all its code. I know when it finishes because it draws something. I thought r would return and .done would execute if the function finished before the time out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: r is being returned. But its being "Resolved" only after 4500 because of the setTimeout. .done will only be called after a promise is Resolved not when it is returned

Comment: and how do I achieve that? if I remove teh setTimeout the done never gets called

Comment: why do you have the timeout at all?

Comment: is "lots of stuff" async code, or long-running local code?

Comment: @Alnitak there are some .getJSon calls that are async within that block. I have the time out because the done would not be executed otherwise

Comment: @Jabda well, it would, so long as you ensured that `r.resolve()` gets called when the final `.getJSON()` function has done its job.  It sounds like your question needs to be re-phrased in terms of the async contents of `jslongfunc` - the other stuff you already have once the promise is resolved appear correct.

Comment: The closing }); for the getJSON is after the resolve and return

Comment: @Jabda well, we can't really help you without seeing more of the contents of `jslongfunc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your promise is resolving **only** when your setTimeout function is calling `r.resolve()` after 4500ms. You need to call `r.resolve()` when all your stuff is done. Maybe something like this...

```
// function definition
var jslongfunc = function(defr) {
    //... do lots of stuff here ...
    defr.resolve();
}

// promise helper
var promise = function (fn) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(fn);
    return dfd.promise();
}
// init the deferred by using the promise helper above and then attach 'done' callback to stop spinner
var rdef = promise(jslongfunc).done(function (response) {
    spinner.stop();
}).fail(function (response) {
    // handle promise failure.
});
```

**Update**

Well now that you put up your using `$.getJSON` you can do the following.

```
function jslongfunc(value) {
  var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    // THIS IS YOUR FIRST promise callback
    // do some stuff with the json you just got
  });
  // return the promise
  return jqxhr;
}

// now handle the spinner stoppage
jslongfunc(value).done(function () {
  spinner.stop();
}).fail(function (data) {
  // handle function failure here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried your code and spinner.stop() never hits

Comment: So spinner.stop() never hits, does jslongfunc finish executing?

Comment: yes it does, but the spinner keeps going so I am assuming done is never called.

Comment: do you get anything from the `.fail` callback? Try to `alert("oops")` from the fail callback and see if its your `jslongfunc` function.

Comment: I put an alert in .fail doesnt seem to go there either

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LNw6R/2/) that I use to hit the Google financial API for stock quotes.

I've added the Ajax events beforesend, complete that turns some gears off and on (very short period of time for this call).

But it will probably give you a start.

Edit: Here's a second [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LNw6R/3/) with more compact code.

JS

```
$('.putmehere1').hide();
var quotevalue;
var symboltopass = "NYSE:SDY";

$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
          url: "https://finance.google.com/finance/info",
        async: false,
     dataType: 'JSONP',
         data: {
                client: 'ig',
                     q: symboltopass
                }
 })
.done( function(data){
                                 var stockInfo = data[0];
                                 console.log( data[0] );
                                 quotevalue = stockInfo.l;
                                 $('.putmehere2').html( '#2 - ' + quotevalue);
                          });
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
      $('.putmehere1').show();
   },
   complete: function(){
      $('.putmehere1').hide();
   }
 });
```